# Storing RSS pubDate in App Engine Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The pubDate in an RSS feed is in the format:

> 2011-12-19T01:56:28-06:00
>
> 2011-10-19T06:11:02+00:00

How can I convert this to a common timezone so I can store it in db.DateTimeProperty() and sort items by date, regardless of timezone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a variant of ISO8601 datetime format.  This is my function for parsing dates like that:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def parse_iso8601_datetime(dtstr, loose=False):
    """
    Convert ISO8601 datetime string and return Python datetime.datetime.
    Specify loose=True for more relaxed parsing accepting eg "YYYY-MM-DD" format.

    Raise ValueError on malformed input.
    """
    dt = None
    if len(dtstr) == 19:    # (eg '2010-05-07T23:12:51')
        dt = datetime.strptime(dtstr, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    elif len(dtstr) == 20:  # (eg '2010-05-07T23:12:51Z')
        dt = datetime.strptime(dtstr, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    elif len(dtstr) == 25:  # (eg '2010-05-07T23:12:51-08:00')
        dt = datetime.strptime(dtstr[0:19], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        tzofs = int(dtstr[19:22])
        dt = dt - timedelta(hours=tzofs)
    else:
        if loose:
            if len(dtstr) == 10:  # (eg '2010-05-07')
                dt = datetime.strptime(dtstr, "%Y-%m-%d")
        if not dt:
            raise ValueError("Invalid ISO8601 format: '%s'" % dtstr)
    return dt
```